# Child to parent class Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to inheritance in C# and my problem is Object Reference not set to an instance of an object from Parent to Child

I tried the debug log from string to parent to child and works now that im experimenting this happens now

This my parent class

```
public class GameManagerRevamped : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Arrays Buttons
    public GameObject[] gameButtons;

    //Arrays ImagesSource
    public Image[] ImagesSource;
    //Source Images
    public Sprite[] BlackImages;

    //Instance Variables
    public int ImagesClick =-1;
    public int buttonOrder;
    public string finalAnswer = "";
    public string TryInheritance;

    public virtual void buttonClicked()
    {
        ImagesSource[ImagesClick].sprite = BlackImages[ImagesClick];
        gameButtons[buttonOrder].SetActive(false);
    }

    public virtual void firstButtonClicked()
    {
        ImagesClick += 1;
        buttonOrder = 0;
        buttonClicked();
        finalAnswer += "";
        Debug.Log(TryInheritance);
    }
}
```

this my Child Class

```
public class FableScript : GameManagerRevamped
{

    public override void buttonClicked()
    {
        base.buttonClicked();
    }

    public override void firstButtonClicked()
    {   
        finalAnswer += "f";
        TryInheritance =finalAnswer;
        ImagesClick += 1;
        buttonOrder = 0;
        buttonClicked();
        base.firstButtonClicked();
    }
}
```

The "TryInheritance" works but the other is on not set to instance object. Point is when I click on the button the it goes to inactive state :))

Comment: `and my problem is Object Reference not set to an instance of an object from Parent to Child` What line of code throws that exception?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from the original question where the exception is being thrown, but it does look very strange that you repeat a number of lines of `firstButtonClicked` in the derived (child) class before then calling the method in the base (parent) class.

When you follow the code path, for example, `ImagesClick` gets incremented twice (once in the derived class and then once in the parent class, the same happens with `buttonClicked()` and my guess (because I don't know the implementation) is that the button goes inactive because `buttonClicked()` is called twice.

One of the advantages of inheritance is that you do not need to repeat common code. Your derived class `firstButtonClicked` method might work with just:

```
public override void firstButtonClicked()
{   
    finalAnswer += "f";
    TryInheritance =finalAnswer;
    base.firstButtonClicked();
}
```